# SPFx web part: wait for fetching data before rendering header

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, microsoft-graph, typescript, graph-api

I already [asked this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260276/spfx-extension-wait-for-fetching-data-before-rendering-header) regarding SPFx extensions.

But now I have the same problem I had in that question, but for a SPFx Web part. I use the exact same `_getUserInformation()` method as mentioned in the answer and which worked for my extension.

```
private _getUserInformation() : Promise<any> {
  const res = this.context.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient()
    .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
    client
      .api('/me')
      .select("department,displayName,companyName,officeLocation")
      .get((error, response: MicrosoftGraph.User, rawResponse?: any) => {
        // do something
      });
    });

  return Promise.resolve<any>(res);
}
```

And I call it like that:

```
public async render(): Promise<void> {
  await this._getUserInformation();
  this._doOtherStuff();
}
```

But _doOtherStuff() gets called before the the _getUserInformation()-method is finished. I know it seems to be the same question as in my other issue, and probably it is, but why is it like that? I really used the exact same code, but this time in a web part, not an extension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are returning a resolved promise, it basically tells the caller "hey I'm done", which in your case might or might not be true depending on the timing of things.
I suggest you return res right away without wrapping it in a returned promise.
Or you could switch to the async/await syntax for this method as well to be consistent.